# How to make a windows service hard to stop?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, service, admin

I work on a windows productivity and monitoring tool for children. I try to create a C# windows service as hard to stop by user as possible. If the user is not an admin it is easy - the service can not be stopped. The problem is when the user has admin rights. Unfortunately thats often the case because kids have admin rights so that they can install apps and games by themselves.

Currently my service runs under Local System and starts automatically after boot up. Ideally the service is supposed to be stopped only by software uninstallation, reinstallation or windows shutdown or restart etc.

Right now I use sort of hack/workaround. I created two services which periodically (every 1-2 seconds) check each other whether the other service is still running and restarts it in case it is not. This is an ugly solution and definitely not foolproof. The services can be stopped if you are fast enough and it might cause problems during uninstallation or computer restart. Thats why I am looking for a better solution.

The best case scenario I would like behaviour similar to the antivirus software service which can not be stopped even by admin. I know this is not possible. I realize that they probably have some special API permissions from [microsoft industry collaboration program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/intelligence/cybersecurity-industry-partners). But I do not want to go this far. I think it would be a little bit overkill. I dont work on antivirus application.

I know that the admin user is always able to find a way to stop the process or service. I just want to achieve something that would at least survive most of the common "child" attacks. Or at least that it would be a lot of pain or work to kill the service so that the user would give up eventually.

How can I make the service hard to stop?

Thanks a lot for the suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getting into the debate on this...

Programs can try to make themselves more difficult to kill (deny PROCESS_TERMINATE access, deny PROCESS_CREATE_THREAD access so people can't CreateRemoteThread(EndProcess), deny PROCESS_VM_WRITE so people can't scribble into your stack and make you doublefault, deny PROCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME so they can't suspend you), but eventually you just can't stop them from, say, elevating to Debug privilege, debugging your process, and moving EIP to "ExitProcess".

Ultimately everything is killable.

You probably want to have a read of:

http://csharptest.net/1043/how-to-prevent-users-from-killing-your-service-process/

and

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040216-00/?p=40603/

Comment: Yes, I totally agree everything is killable. I just want to make it hard to kill so that most of the users would give up. Thanks a lot. The first link seems interesting I will check it out.